# AFNetworking UIImageView need scroll to load the images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm inserting images in a UITableViewCell with AFNetworking. The problem is that i need to scroll the table to see the images.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Recipe *recipe = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = recipe.value;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[BaseURLString stringByAppendingString:recipe.img]];
   [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you show your setImageWithURL?

Comment: Its an AFNetworking method. I'm considering doing it on my own way with a success block and then using reloadRowAtIndexPath method on the  UITableView, but must be some trick with it cause is a common issue, thought

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is such a method already implemented by AFNetworking in UIImageView+AFNetworking category.

```
[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    blockImageView.image = image;
} failure:nil];
```

Note that if you pass in nil in success the image is set to the imageview you call the method on. In my case imageView.

So here i guess you can do reload data if you need.

Comment: [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:req placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        cell.imageView.image = image;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    } failure:nil]; if it can help anybody

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Peter Segerblom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19270159/947342), I would recommend using a `__weak` reference in place of the `__block` blockImageVariable variable to avoid a retain cycle.

If you just use `__block`, the copy of the imageView will never be deallocated and the count will always remain even after the tableView is gone because the pointer is referencing another memory address.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell text";

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
    __weak UITableView *weakTableView = tableView;
    __weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
    __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = cell.imageView;
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                          placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                                   success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                       weakImageView.image = image;
                                       if ([weakTableView.visibleCells containsObject:weakCell]) {
                                           [weakTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                                       }
                                 } failure:nil];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@pxpgraphics: I had to replace

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
```

with

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
```

to prevent a runtime error .

Answer (score 1):

Swift equivalent:

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: book.mediumImageURL)
cell.imageView.setImageWithURLRequest(request, placeholderImage: nil, success: { [weak cell] request, response, image in
    if cell {
        cell!.imageView.image = image
    }

    if tableView.visibleCells().bridgeToObjectiveC().containsObject(cell) {
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
    }
}, failure:nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best code to use:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myimageurl.com"];  //Change this URL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    __weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
    __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = cell.imageView;
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"granaziOrange"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        weakImageView.image = image;
        [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to get image");
    }];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This post has an answer that works: http://jabbleashish.blogspot.com/2013/12/setting-uitableviewcell-imageview-via.html

```
NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_URL"]];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest placeholderImage:nil
success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
        NSLog(@"success");
        cell.imageView.image = image;
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        cell.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell setNeedsLayout];// To update the cell {if not using this, your image is not showing over cell.}
}failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Failure");}
```

This seems straightforward without having to reload the cell according to index path.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the cell type - if you have a custom cell with your own UIImageView inside, make sure you DON'T call its outlet "imageView"! Because there is already internal imageView inside every cell.
I solved the problem by renaming linked IBOutlet with something like *myImageView and now everything works fine with code:

```
[cell.myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placehold.it/100x100"]];
```